# How to set flag increase 1, after php and js use ajax upload file success?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

try to make:
after user upload file if success show img(pass the `$filetype_accept` statement),
add attr `id=1` in `.upload_img` and each time upload file id increase 1 `id=2, id=3..`.
only if refresh page, then clear container and recount.

I set the flag `$layer` to count how many img upload success, but after upload 2nd img  the attr still `id=1`.
below is my code, any suggestion to make it work?

Thanks.

php

```
$filename = $_FILES['file_upload_tmp']['name'];
$filetmp_name = $_FILES['file_upload_tmp']['tmp_name'];
$filetype = $_FILES['file_upload_tmp']['tmp_name'];
$filetype_accept = $filetype == 'image/jpg';

$layer = 0;
if($_FILES){
    if($filetype_accept){
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp_name, 'upload/tmp/'.$filename);
        $layer = $layer + 1;
        print"
            <div class=\"img_wp\">
                <div class=\"upload_img\" id=\"$layer\">
                    <img src=\"upload/tmp/$filename\">
                </div>
            </div>
        ";
        return $layer;
    }
    else{
        print"upload file error, plz upload file type: $filetype";
    }
}
else{
    print"
        <div class=\"upload\">
            <form enctype=\"multipart/form_data\">
                <input type=\"file\" name=\"file_upload_tmp\">
                <input type=\"submit\" value=\"upload\" class=\"btn\">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class=\"container\"></div>
    ";
}
```

js

```
$('.btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var uf = $('.upload form');
    var fd = new FormData(uf[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(html){
            var img = $(html).filter('.img_wp').html();
            $('.container').append(img);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Save the id in `$_SESSION` and make an ajax call that set the id to 0 on page load... Then just increment the value in the `$_SESSION` by 1 on each successfull ipload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll send the data to the server `fd.append('layer', $('.upload_img').attr('id'));` then process it on the server `$layer = (int)$_POST['layer'];`.